# Windows service and timer in C#

Tags: c#

I need help to write a windows service with a timer that can call 3 different function(events) in 3 different times every day.
Some code example please. Thank you.

```
 private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        this.timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(60000); 
        this.timer1.AutoReset = true;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Elapsed);
        this.timer1.Start();

    }

private DateTime _lastRun1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
private DateTime _lastRun2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
private DateTime _lastRun3 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (_lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date && DateTime.Now.Hour == 13)
        {
            //call functionX

         DateTime _lastRun1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        }
        if (_lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date && DateTime.Now.Hour == 14)
        {
           //call functionY
         DateTime _lastRun2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        }
  if (_lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date && DateTime.Now.Hour == 16)
        {
           //call functionXY
         DateTime _lastRun3 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: We won't provide "example code" for you - please show at least some attempt at researching the problem yourself, and there are plenty of examples on programming blogs and MSDN, for example.

Comment: "Some code example please. Thank you.". This site doesn't work like this....we help you with code YOU write first and help you fix it.

Comment: Aye. And anyway you might be able to get away with one or more console applications and just use the Windows Task Scheduler to run them at the appropriate times. Simpler than implementing your own timed service.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write 3 distinct applications and let the Windows task scheduler execute them at the appropriate times? This will probably be a lot easier than trying to get your own scheduling logic right, which can often be more complicated than you'd expect.

Comment: I know it is much easier with Windows task scheduler, but the requirement is, it must be a service application

Comment: @Argoshi - out of interest why does it need to be a service application?

Comment: it must be running as a process in background, furthermore the 3 function(events) have some dependent on each others which it make appropriate to be in one application.

Comment: @Argoshi windows task scheduler runs in the background though, so that's not an argument if used with a console app (no UI). You don't say what you mean by dependencies. If it just means they share code then the answer is a single console application but that takes an argument to say which method is invoked when it is run.